# JSON::ParserError in CoursesController#index

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

I am a beginner of Ruby on Rails and web development. I am taking a online course and keep failing the lecture example.

My problem is my courses_controller, index action.

Controller: my_first_app/controllers/courses_controller.rb

```
class CoursesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @search_term = 'jhu'
    @courses = Coursera.for(@search_term)
  end
end
```

Model: my_first_app/models/coursera.rb

```
class Coursera
  include HTTParty

  #default_options.update(verify: false) # Turn off SSL verification
  base_uri 'https://api.coursera.org/api/catalog.v1/courses'
  default_params fields: "smallIcon,shortDescription", q: "search"
  format :json

  def self.for term
    get("", query: { query: term})["elements"]
  end
end
```

View: my_first_app/views/index.html.erb

```
<h1>Search for - <%= @search_term %> </h1>
<table border = "1">
    <tr>
        <th>Image</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Description</th>
    </tr>

<%= @courses.each do |course| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= image_tag(course["smallIcon"]) %></td>
        <td><%= course["name"] %></td>
        <td><%= course["shortDescription"] %> </td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

Routes: my_first_app/config/routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'courses/index'
  get 'greeter/hello'
  get 'greeter/goodbye'
end
```

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '4.2.3'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

group :development, :test do
gem 'byebug'
gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
gem 'spring'
gem 'httparty', '0.13.5'
end
```

I added the last gem to the Gemfile and run bundle, then I controlled +c to stopped and restarted the server and I got the error message:

```
JSON::ParserError in CoursesController#index
```

[error message screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aiFam.png)

I think it is saying that I parse a HTML instead of JSON, but I don't know how to fix it. Any help will be appreciated.
Original repository: https://github.com/jhu-ep-coursera/fullstack-course1-module3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [API documentation](https://docs.google.com/document/d/15gwppUMLp0s1OhbzFZvFSeTbvFkRfSFIkiIKrEP6cUA/edit#heading=h.wpqp7pmo0g4y) for Coursera, it looks like your `base_uri` might need to be:

```
base_uri 'https://api.coursera.org/api/courses.v1'
```

and then for `fields` in the `default_params` should (maybe) be:

```
default_params fields: "photoUrl,description", q: "search"
```

(changing the other occurrences of `'smallIcon'` and `'shortDescription'` with `'photoUrl'` and `'description'` in your app as well, since I don't see those fields in the api docs).

Once those changes are made you should end up going to urls like https://api.coursera.org/api/courses.v1?q=search&query=ruby&fields=photoUrl,description which is returning valid JSON. The current `base_uri` you are using is sending you to an HTML error page telling you **Action not found**. Since that's an HTML page, JSON can't parse it.

If you look at the date on the last commit in the Github repository you linked, the last commit was in November 2015, so nearly 2 years ago. Just super out of date, the API has probably changed a fair bit since then.